# as3 htmltext and css classes

Tags: css, actionscript-3, flash

I cannot seem to get a css class to work

I've got a `h1` style, and a class to set the justify property

```
.right {
    text-align:right;
}
.left {
    text-align:left;
}
.center {
    text-align:center;
}
.justify {
    text-align:justify;
}
h1{
    font-size:68;
}
```

and a simple html code

```
<h1 class="left">left</h1>
<h1 class="center">center</h1>
<div class="right"><h1>right</h1></div>
```

But it seems like the class selectors are not doing anything, is there something I'm missing or is this just not possible, or a trick to get this to work?

---

my test code:

```
var $style:StyleSheet = new StyleSheet();
$style.parseCSS(".right {text-align:right;}.left {text-align:left;}.center {text-align:center;}.justify {text-align:justify;}h1{font-size:20}");

var $tf:TextField = new TextField;
$tf.styleSheet = $style;
$tf.border = true;
$tf.width = 600;
$tf.height = 600;
$tf.htmlText = '<h1 class="left">left</h1><h1 class="center">center</h1><div class="right"><h1>right</h1></div>';
addChild($tf)
```

Comment: The CSS stuff in ActionScript is... weird. Just make a HTML5 app instead :P

Answer (score 1):

AS3 has very limited support for HTML tags, I was able to get your example working by wrapping your `h1` tags in `p` tags and; I also had to set the textfield to be multiline:

```
var $style:StyleSheet = new StyleSheet();
$style.parseCSS(".right {text-align:right;}.left {text-align:left;}.center {text-align:center;}.justify {text-align:justify;}h1{font-size:20}");

var $tf:TextField = new TextField;
$tf.styleSheet = $style;
$tf.border = true;
$tf.width = 600;
$tf.height = 600;
$tf.multiline = true;

$tf.htmlText = '<p class="left"><h1>left</h1></p><p class="center"><h1>center</h1></p><p class="right"><h1>right</h1></p>';
addChild($tf)
```

Comment: The html code is supplied externally, so the only way I can make that work is if I convert the tags in flash (encapsulate and move the class of the `h#` to the `p` tag)

Comment: Ah, didn't realize the HTML was external. I'm not sure my solution is the best, then. Sorry.